# PHP: UTF-8 character gets messy in function which takes the first letter from each word of a sentence

Tags: php, utf-8

I have this function which when executed it returns the first letters of each word of a string.

```
function initials($stringsoftext) {
    $retturns = '';
    foreach (explode(' ', $stringsoftext) as $word)
        $retturns .= ($word[0]);
    return $retturns;
}
```

Everything works fine. The only problem is that when the words begin with special characters it starts to get messy. 
For example "**test økonomi**" become "**t�**" instead of "**tø**"
How can i correct this?

Comment: What is the text-encoding in the generated HTML-code?

Comment: i have this in my header "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `$word[0]` takes the *first byte* of a string, whereas you are using a multi-bye encoding. So a character may consist of multiple bytes. In case of a `ø` character it consists of 2 bytes: `0xC3 0xB8`

That is how you would extract the first character instead:

```
mb_substr($word, 0, 1, 'utf8')
```

Working demo: http://ideone.com/XVnC87

Comment: You sure he only wants the first codepoint and not the first glyph?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm not sure I understand the difference between a codepoint and a glyph. I always thought it's the same (to be precise: that a codepoint just represents a glyph). Am I missing something?

Comment: @zerkms They're not quite the same; e.g. combining diacritics can result in multiple codepoints contributing to a glyph, but it's probably close enough for most purposes.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer. Thank you @zerkms

Comment: @Wooble: yep, I see now. Now curious how would one take that into account. /me went googling

Comment: @Wooble: At least if you are guaranteed NFC or NFKC. Still, the bug can bite you...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mb_substr` with `mb_internal_encoding` as in example:

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo initials('ąęść óęłęł');



function initials($stringsoftext) {
    $retturns = '';
    foreach (explode(' ', $stringsoftext) as $word) {
        $retturns .= mb_substr($word,0,1);
    }
    return $retturns;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Complementing various answers above, you could convert utf-8 (to be precise, assumed as utf-8) encoded character to its ISO 8859 counterpart.
No multibyte support required, as it's not enabled by default in many PHP configurations.

Use [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in order to do so

```
<?php
function initials($stringsoftext) {
    $retturns = '';
    foreach (explode(' ', utf8_decode($stringsoftext)) as $word)
        $retturns .= ($word[0]);
    return $retturns;

}

echo initials("test økonomi");
//return tø
?>
```

Edit: This approach could break if the characters being converted is not defined on ISO 8859 charset (e.g non latin symbols). Just to reiterate if PHP multi byte support is turned on, mb_substr() solutions is certainly the most appropriate as it is able to properly process the string in utf8 encoding.

Comment: What if `ISO 8859` doesn't have a given character defined?

Comment: In that case, perhaps we'd better use the iconv() function (e.g append the TRANSLIT/IGNORE option), so unknown character won't get outputted as as garbage. In my opinion utf8_encode() works well for converting common subset of latin characters (such as the diacritics and common latin symbol). I could be wrong, though.

Comment: "so unknown character won't get outputted as as garbage" --- are you seriously proposing to treat characters that are not in `ISO 8859` as a *garbage*? People with non-latin symbols in their names won't be happy after your advice.

Comment: Not sure what are you getting at.. but pardon me, English is not my first language. By _garbage_ what I meant was a bunch of unreadable characters. So allow to me rephrase my statement: "so any characters that are not defined in ISO 8859 would still be converted correctly to the its nearest transliteration, or not printed at all".

Comment: `"Иван"` --- here is my first name. Try to extract the first letter from it using your solution. The desired result it: `"И"`. Your code returns `?`: http://ideone.com/aQSSJK

Comment: Wow seriously? I was trying to provide _alternative_ when the PHP multibyte support is not available. If multibyte support is available by all means your solution is truly the most appropriate and inclusive for people with and without a latin symbol in their names. I didn't expect  programming Q&A site could get this personal. Feel free to downvote my answer if you are not happy with it.

Comment: "personal" --- how so? I don't care your solution is wrong. I just mentioned that your solution is going to break valid data. "Feel free to downvote my answer if you are not happy with it." --- as I said, *I don't care* if you are proposing to use something that breaks user's data. "you could **always** convert utf-8" --- now you see, that your answer is *technically inaccurate* that has nothing to do with personalities.

Comment: And your solution won't work at all with php multibyte extension turned off. I guess you already get your points conveyed, and so do I. Feel free to continue the discussion (not with me though, I don't intend to participate any further). Oh also I'm sorry because your first name can't be correctly translated with my solution, Ivan.

Comment: it is silly you thought that it hurts me just because your code doesn't work. The name was chosen randomly just because I can type it in a second. For the very same demonstration reason it could be a Chinese name, if I only knew Chinese language. You're being childish here. And, yes, now -1 is mine, just because **you** have started being personal.

Comment: Suggesting ISO-8859 in the 21st century? Seriously? You're claiming that it would break non-Latin characters, but it would break Latin characters too. Try it with `ś`. Or `ı`. Or `ħ`. Or `ệ`. Seriously, ISO 8859 is dead and trying to use it ends up with more broken text than ever.

Comment: @KarolS Hi, thanks for the comment. I said non latin symbol is one _example_.. no where I said it's the only one that would break. Zerkms has kindly corrected my answer. So I stand corrected and my disclaimer was already there prior to your comment (i.e keep using utf8 and use mb_ variant of string function. Since it's the best solution where available). So what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: If you really want to support incomplete installations of PHP, then implement simplistic UTF-8 support yourself. Take the first byte, check its value, and decide how many bytes you need to chop off from the beginning of the string.

Comment: Cool. I'm sure your comments would be extremely useful for future reader. Hope that helps.